# Expected value of a complicated function of more than one random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Assume we have random variables with Probability Density Functions (pdf) as follows $$\omega_i \sim f_{1},\,\,\,\,\ i \in[1:n]$$
$$ \gamma= \{\gamma_1,\cdots,\gamma_n\}  \sim f_2: \text{joint pdf of the set}$$

Now consider $T$, a function of these random variables listed above, as follows

$$T= \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i \left(1+ \sum_{j=1, \ j\neq i}^n f(\omega_j-\omega_i)\right)^2$$

where $f(.)$ is a function of the difference of the random variables.

**Question:**

What is the expected value of $exp (T)$ i.e.

$$\mathbb{E} \biggl[\text{exp}\left(T\right)\biggl]$$

**My thoughts:**

1- I think we need to first find the distribution of $\omega_j-\omega_i$ by convolution. Let us assume this is possible and the pdf of the difference is $f_D(d)$.

2- Do I then need to find the joint distribution of the functions $ \omega_j-\omega_i$?

3-Moreover I think we have to use the following property,assuming $f_Y(y)$ is the pdf of $Y$

$$E_{X,Y}\big[ g(X, Y)\big]= E_{X} \bigg[E_{Y}\big[g(x,y)\big]\bigg]=E_{X}\bigg[ \int_{y}f_Y(y)g(x,y)dy\bigg]   $$

It is the indices in the expression $T$ that are confusing me.

Any advice would much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a rule which is sometimes called the "law of the unconscious statistician", which says that to get the expectation of a (measurable) function $f$ of a random variable $X$, you don't need to calculate the distribution of the function. Instead you just have, supposing for the moment $X$ is real-valued with density $p$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) p(x) dx.$$

This is *usually* easier to calculate than finding the distribution of $f(X)$ itself. In your case, changing notation to match yours, you want

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(T(\omega,\gamma)) (f_1(\omega))^n f_2(\gamma) d \omega d \gamma.$$

Comment: Thanks, but $T$ is function of the difference $\omega_i-\omega_j$ why did you multiply by $f_2(\omega)$?

Comment: @Henry The multiplication by $f_2(\omega)$ is because that is the probability density at that particular (vector) $\omega$. It's the same as the previous form. $T$ depends on $\omega_i - \omega_j$ but *in particular* it is a function of $\omega$. In other words, if you tell me $\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_n$, then I can compute $T$. This is convenient because we already have the distribution of $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_n)$ in the form of $f_2$.

Comment: But shouldn't we multiply by the pdf of the difference $f_D(d)$ in my notation....

Comment: @Henry No, you don't have to: the difference is still a function of $\omega$. This will work with whatever (measurable) function you want.

Comment: Thanks, but in either way: whether I multiply by the pdf of the difference or by the pdf of $\omega$ both ways are correct? What is the difference then? Moreover should I be multiplying by $f_2(\omega)$ or the joint pdf...

Comment: You can do it either way, it just depends on what's convenient. What you wrote seemed to suggest that my form would be convenient, since it's in terms of the given $f_2$. And I meant the joint pdf. (I'm not sure what you meant by $f_2$ if it isn't the joint pdf, though.)

Comment: But both ways have different structure $\int exp(T(\omega))f_2(\omega)$ $\neq$ $\int exp(T(\omega_j-\omega_i))f_D(d)$, am i missing something out?

Comment: @Henry You get a different integrand, just like you get a different integrand when you change variables in calculus. You also have a different type of integral: integrating against the differences requires $n^2$ integrations, since there are $n^2$ differences. ($n$ of them are always zero, but still.) Integrating against $\omega$ itself requires only $n$ integrations.

Comment: @Henry A more elementary example: suppose you're integrating $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{x-y} dx dy$. This depends only on the difference, so maybe you want to change variables to involve $x-y$. So you define new coordinates $(u,v)=(x-y,y)$ (for example). This transformation has Jacobian determinant $1$. Now the outer limit is still from $0$ to $1$ while the inner limit is from $-v$ to $1-v$. Hence the integral is the same as $\int_0^1 \int_{-v}^{1-v} e^u du dv$. The two forms we're discussing are equivalent in the same respect, there is just a change of variables in the middle.

Comment: I agree thank you, if I may ask, in your notation $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ means $n$ integrals? Why $n$?

Comment: @Henry There is an integral with respect to $\omega_1$, with respect to $\omega_2$, etc. up to $\omega_n$. Integrating against the differences there is an integral for each $d_{ij}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $j=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Wait in all your comments you meant to write $f_1$ instead of $f_2$ right? Because $f_1$ is the distribution of $\omega$ while $f_2$ is the joint distribution of $\gamma$?

Comment: @Henry I can't really tell which is which in what you've written. You should be integrating against the joint pdf of $\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_n$ in the notation of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I appreciate it, I want to make it easier for everyone and probably add this example to the question above, if $\omega_i$ are i.i.d $\sim \text{U}[-\pi,\pi]$, can I say that the expected value of $T$ is $\mathbb{E}_{\gamma}[ \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi})^n exp\left(T(\omega)\right) ]$?

Comment: @Henry I don't think I understand what you mean by $\mathbb{E}_\gamma$ there. The expected value of $\exp(T(\omega))$ would be $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \dots \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left ( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \right )^n \exp(T(\omega)) d \omega_1 d \omega_2 \dots d \omega_n$.

Comment: please note that the expression $T$ has $\gamma$ which is also a random variable that is why I have $\mathbb{E}_\gamma$

Comment: Ah, now I see the difference between $\gamma$ and $\omega$. Then yeah, you have $\mathbb{E}_\gamma$ of what I wrote.

Comment: awesome thanks @Ian